# Jhipster error An unexpected error occurred: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bower

Tags: jhipster

Because of the Chinese GFW, when I finished the Hipster configuration and generate the code, run via `mvn spring-boot:run` I got an issue with the message as follow:

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bower: tunneling socket could not be
>   established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3128".

I did something as Hipster office site to set the proxy, but it doesn't work.

I set the `~/.npmrc` as follow: `proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 http-proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 http_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 registry=registry.npm.taobao.org`

Could someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I set the ~/.npmrc as follow: proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 https-proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128 registry=registry.npm.taobao.org

Comment: Awesome! I've got it done today! the "yarn.lock" file causes this problem.